# java - requestparam flooded with old values from a old call

Tags: java, spring

i am passing `@Requestparam` `/register?name=newname` from a page. but next time i call a page `/register/confirm`, it's showing the param in the url like `/register/confirm?name=newname`. how to avoid this?

Comment: Paste some code so it is more clear. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. This could happen because `name` is being confused with a Path in a `@ModelAttribute`. Do you have any such `ModelAttribute` in the same view ?

I dont know how your view works, but it's best that you refer to the `@RequestParam` as `${param.name}` rather than `name` (in case you're not already)